# How to pass remote file resources as input to ResourceLoader

Tags: java, file, remote-access

The following is a snippet to load bank location specific information a JSON file.

```
@Autowired
private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

readFile("classpath:/HCBL.json");

private InputStream readFile(String fileName) throws Exception {
    Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource(fileName);
    return resource.getInputStream();
}
```

Instead of reading from a local file, I would like to point to a remote GitHub repository (say https://github.com/razorpay/ifsc-api/tree/master/data) instead of copying files into the classpath (say src/main/resources) and load them directly

Comment: Just use it as you need. For example `readFile("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/razorpay/ifsc-api/master/data/ABNA.json")`. It will return you a stream of file content. Because spring uses `DefaultResourceLoader` which in implementation uses `UrlResource` if it is not a filesystem or classpath resource

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly. You would like to automatically retrieve list of json files from given path of repository and then read all those files.

This code is a simplified example how to achieve it:

```
@Autowired
private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

@Bean
CommandLineRunner run(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
    return a ->
    {
        // (1)
        List<UrlObject> urlObjects = objectMapper.readValue(
                new URL("https://api.github.com/repos/razorpay/ifsc-api/contents/data"),
                new TypeReference<>() {}); 
        
        List<String> urls = urlObjects.stream()
                .map(obj -> obj.name)
                .filter(name -> name.endsWith("json")) // (2)
                .map(name -> "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/razorpay/ifsc-api/master/data/" + name)
                .peek(System.out::println) // (3)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        // do whatever you need with given urls
        for (String url : urls) {
            InputStream is = readFile(url);
        }
    };
}

private InputStream readFile(String fileName) throws Exception {
    Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource(fileName);
    return resource.getInputStream();
}
static class UrlObject {
    @JsonProperty("name")
    String name;
}
```

(1) First we are using github API: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/contents?apiVersion=2022-11-28#get-repository-content in order to retrieve contents of given path in repository.

(2) Additional filter for json files is applied.

(3) just for debug, can be removed later